# Stop GIF Animation in WebView of UWP

Tags: animation, webview, uwp, gif

I am using a webview in my UWP application where a gif image will be provided from external web. There is a requirement that, I need to stop the GIF animation after staying 5 seconds on the page. How can I accomplish this??? I was looking for injecting Java Script, but couldn't find out the actual way . Can anyone help please???

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario, a common workaround is to use InvokeScriptAsync with the JavaScript eval function to use the HTML event handlers

For stopping Gif, you could use the following javascript method.

```
 [].slice.apply(document.images).filter(is_gif_image).map(freeze_gif);
 function is_gif_image(i) {
     return /^(?!data:).*\.gif/i.test(i.src);
 }



function freeze_gif(i) {
     var c = document.createElement('canvas');
     var w = c.width = i.width;
     var h = c.height = i.height;
     c.getContext('2d').drawImage(i, 0, 0, w, h);
     try {
         i.src = c.toDataURL("image/gif"); 
     } catch (e) { 
         for (var j = 0, a; a = i.attributes[j]; j++)
             c.setAttribute(a.name, a.value);
         i.parentNode.replaceChild(c, i);
     }
 }
```

And inject it with the eval function 5 seconds after the page is Navigation Completed.

```
 private async void MyWebView_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
 {
     await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
     var function = @"[].slice.apply(document.images).filter(is_gif_image).map(freeze_gif);
 function is_gif_image(i) {
     return /^(?!data:).*\.gif/i.test(i.src);
 }
 function freeze_gif(i) {
     var c = document.createElement('canvas');
     var w = c.width = i.width;
     var h = c.height = i.height;
     c.getContext('2d').drawImage(i, 0, 0, w, h);
     try {
         i.src = c.toDataURL('image / gif'); 
     } catch (e) { // cross-domain -- mimic original with all its tag attributes
         for (var j = 0, a; a = i.attributes[j]; j++)
             c.setAttribute(a.name, a.value);
         i.parentNode.replaceChild(c, i);
     }}";
    
     await MyWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { function });
 }
```